# what actually the function for e(g,g)^xy

Tags: encryption, abe

I doing a project using ABE "***Attribute-Based-Encryption***" but i didn't understand what actually the function for $e(g,g)^xy$.
Just tell what's the calculation need to perform here. I gone through no of publications and thesis but i didn't understand this.

$PK = (T_1 = g ^{t_1} , ..., T_{|u|} = g^ {t|U|} , Y = e(g, g)^ y )$

Using the above values how can i calculate PK.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

This is a [bilinear pairing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing-based_cryptography) used in cryptography. More precisely it's an evaluation of an appropriate pairing friendly elliptic curve equation.([1](http://eprint.iacr.org/2004/064.pdf),[2](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/~ajmeneze/publications/pairings.pdf),[3](http://eprint.iacr.org/2006/372.pdf),[4](http://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/thesis.pdf),[5](http://doras.dcu.ie/15046/1/008.pdf))